# Stick a background behind a div form

Tags: html, css

I have a form I'm looking to place an image behind, like in this example:

[image: Effect I'm trying to accomplish]

The code is as follows:

```css
#minicontact{width:25%;float:right;margin:-525px 155px -5px 0;}
#miniformtitle{margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
#buttonmini{cursor:pointer;width:150px !important;height:60px !important;font-size:120% !important;text-align:center !important;background-color:#6db9fa !important;color:#ffffff !important;border-radius:20px !important; margin-top:20px; display:block; padding:0px;
margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<div id="minicontact">
  <h3 id="miniformtitle">Get Started</h3>
  <form class="contact" action="&lt;?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?&gt;#cform1" method="post" name="simp_cont">
    <p><br /> <input id="captcha" class="input" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" name="captcha" type="text" /><br /> <input id="name" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="NAME" /><br /> <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"
      /><br /> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" /><br /> <input id="footage" name="footage" type="text" placeholder="ESTIMATED SQUARE FOOTAGE" /><br /> <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea><input name="form_name" type="hidden" value="contact_form" />
     <button type="submit" id="buttonmini" name='submit'>SEND MESSAGE</button></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

The image I'm trying to use as the background is:

[image: Background image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google probably won't allow you to see the image in run script, but the CSS is there for you to achieve it :)

```css
#minicontact {
  width:400px;
  height:500px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ebebeb;
  background:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/22/53/heart-1776746_1280.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="minicontact">
  <h3 id="miniformtitle">Get Started</h3>
  <form class="contact" action="&lt;?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?&gt;#cform1" method="post" name="simp_cont">
    <p><br /> <input id="captcha" class="input" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" name="captcha" type="text" /><br /> <input id="name" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="NAME" /><br /> <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"
      /><br /> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" /><br /> <input id="footage" name="footage" type="text" placeholder="ESTIMATED SQUARE FOOTAGE" /><br /> <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="COMMENTS"></textarea><input name="form_name" type="hidden" value="contact_form" />
     <button type="submit" id="buttonmini" name='submit'>SEND MESSAGE</button></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a background image via css, and you're good to go.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've actually tried that, and because of how the div is laid out, it is much too small and doesn't extend like it does in the example image.